# EY can't create directory:" "No space left on device"

Tags: engineyard

I'm trying to [apply the patch for Ghost vulnerability](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/105852596-GHOST-CVE-2015-0235-vulnerability), and after removing the instances and adding new ones (on Stagging env), I'm getting `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/data/{my_dir}’: No space left on device` when trying to deploy.

It might be unrelated with the instance refresh (I did the same on Testing without issues). What can be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error was very self explaining. It turns that when I changed the Utility instance, I assigned it a 15 GB Volume, when it needs more.